# Readiness Probe for Docker Splunk inside Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ansible, splunk

The docker-splunk image has an added layer of complexity because it has the ansible configurator doing the initial setup.  Ansible even restarts the splunk program as part of the setup.

I'm having trouble thinking of an appropriate kubernetes readiness probe.  TCP passes as soon as it gets a valid return.  But the ansible playbooks need at least another 10 minutes before they're finished.

I currently use an initial delay, but I want something smarter.  I'm thinking a command type probe that will look for when the ansible playbooks are complete.  But I don't know where to look.

I guess this means I have to learn ansible now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a startup probe for this which can have long time wait and is made specifically for slow startup containers. The startup probe can check the status of the ansible build to tell successful startup or not.